# Non-isomorphic cubic fields with a given discriminant

Tags: polynomials, number-fields, mathematical-software, magma, discriminant

For a cubic field $K$ with defining polynomial $P(x)=x^3 + \frac{39}{25}x^2 + \frac{22}{25}x +\frac{4}{25}$ Magma calculates the discriminant $D=-3340$.

```
R<x> := PolynomialRing(Rationals());
P := x^3 + 39/25*x^2 + 22/25*x + 4/25;
K<z> := NumberField(P);
"Field K:", K;
"Discriminant(K) =", Discriminant(K);
-------------------------------------
Field K: Number Field with defining polynomial x^3 + 39/25*x^2 + 22/25*x + 4/25 over the Rational Field
Discriminant(K) = -3340
```

We tried to search for cubic fields with $|D|=3340$ in the [database of John W. Jones online](http://hobbes.la.asu.edu/NFDB/) but couldn't find any.

```
Search restrictions:
|discriminant| = 3340
degree = 3
Results below are proven complete.
There are no fields in the database matching your search parameters.
```

> **Question:** Is there a way to build a list of all non-isomorphic cubic fields $K$ with a given discriminant $D$ using any of the computer algebra systems (Magma, SageMath, PARI/GP, Mathematica, Maple)?

Comment: There's a slightly annoying feature of Magma involved here: Discriminant(NumberField(P)) does actually NOT give the field discriminant, but the discriminant of a defining (maybe manipulated to have integer coefficients) polynomial! If you want the field discriminant, you need to ask for Discriminant(MaximalOrder(NumberField(P))) - which in your example turns out to be -835, and is in the databases.

Comment: Thank you, Joachim! Given that Discriminant(MaximalOrder($K$))$=-835$, is there a way of figuring out cubic field $K$ in Magma rather than looking it up online?

Comment: In this particular case, since the  discriminant of the cubic field is squarefree, the corresponding $S_3$-Galois extension is necessarily an unramified cubic extension of its quadratic subfield $K=Q(\sqrt{-835})$. So if there were another cubic field with the same discriminant, $K$ would have two different unramified degree-3 extensions and in particular class number divisible by 9. But Magma confirms that the class number is 6.

Comment: Thank you, Joachim! Back to my original question. Let's say $|D|=697$, also squarefree. For $D=697$, how would I find the corresponding cubic field $K(D)$ in Magma without looking it up online? How would I confirm in Magma that for $D=-697$ the corresponding cubic field  does not exist.

Comment: Look up the command "nflist" in Pari/GP. For instance nflist("S3",697) outputs $[x^3-7*x-5]$ as unique cubic field with $|D|=697$, and since its discriminant is equal to $+697$, there is no cubic field with $D=-697$. In addition to a single D, you can specify a range, and/or a signature.

Comment: Thank you, Henry! I looked it up, that's a great place for me to start. I will write up a short answer in Magma later for future reference.